# Magento Database Relations

Tags: database, sql, query

I have a system when customer can create their own products. I added a custom attribute to the products called creator_id to save the id of the customer who created it.
Everything is working perfectly but now I want to retrieve all the products created by the customer. What SQL query can I use to retrieve that information.
I would need to check if the `customer id = creator_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('creator_id', $customId);
```

Comment: If I add a custom attribute to the addAttributeToSelect() for ex: product_info which stores product info, I would retrieve all the info of all the products that have 'creator_id' = $customId?

Comment: yes. `*` means "add all the attributes", but you can add only what you need.

Comment: Thanks Marius you did in a minute what I was trying with SQL for 2 hours